# Grails Datasources "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"

Tags: hibernate, grails, datasource

I'm using the Grails Datasources plugin in my app, and am having issues persisting a (chidl) domain class referencing a readonly association (parent) class. For example:

```
/* Parent domain class; a read-only datasource using the Datasources plugin */
class Parent {
  //...Some fields
}

/* Child domain class, referencing the parent class */
class Child
  // Some fields
  static hasOne = [parent:Parent]
}
```

When I try and persist my child class, I get this error

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`foo`.`child`, CONSTRAINT `FK38A5EE5F707D1A2B` 
FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `parent` (`id`))
```

I noticed that Grails creates a local, empty copy of the referenced table from (readonly) `datasource A` to my local (writeable) `datasource B` when the tables are created on startup. Could it be referencing this table (and its newly created FK) instead? If so, why does it not enforce the FK constraint on the actual datasource (i.e. in `datasource A`)?

I'm fairly new to Grails, and have been unable to find solutions to this specific issue anywhere else, so sorry if this sounds like a stupid question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin would not support relationships like this across databases. GORM probably isn't aware that the other domain class lives in another database.

The way around this error would be to store a reference to the parent row, something like:

```
class Child{
      long parentId      
      Parent getParent(){
           Parent.get( parentId )
      }
}
```

See this: http://markmail.org/message/omllq46sn3d2l6ah

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, and the link. Can you advise what my setter would/should look like? Wouldn't I also need a Parent reference? 

Also, I noticed that, despite marking the field as transient, it still created the foreign key reference to the Parent table in my read-only datasource when I dropped and recreated the database/tables - why?

Comment: Your setter would just be something like void setParent( parent ){ parentId = parent.id }

Comment: It probably creates the parent because dbCreate is set in the datasource and GORM is not that smart.

Comment: Thanks again Tomas. Unfortunately I'm still getting the FK error. Here's my child class:

`class Child {`
...
`static transients = ['parentId']`
`Parent getParent(){Parent.get(parentId)}`
`void setParent(p){this.parentId=p.id}`

I have the dbCreate('update') property set on my read-only datasource

Comment: your transient should be parent.

Comment: Thanks Tomas - that sorted it